# winforms c# cmd output to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

Необходимо реализовать печать консольного вывода в текстбокс формы.
Делал так:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd");
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(ip_string);
cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
........
void SortOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(e.Data);
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        textBox4.AppendText(e.Data ?? string.Empty);
    }));
}
```

Выполняю команду curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 http://checkip.amazonaws.com

При таком подходе в текстбокс попадает полностью весь текст из cmd, включающий не только нужный мне ip адрес, но и саму команду и прочий ненужный мне хлам.
Подскажите, как получить в результате именно результат выполнения команды, а не все сразу?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в `textBox` попадает то, что Вы в него вносите. Программа делает только то, что написал программист. Не более.

Вы добавляете туда всё подряд. В результате всё подряд и выводится.

Получив результат, просто отфильтруйте лишнее перед выводов в `textBox` и Ваша проблема будет решена.

Comment: А можно конкретнее?
Каким образом указать программе, что нужно добавить в текстбокс только ответы, полученные в консоль?

Comment: @iamx4nd3r, у Вас же есть образец вывода при выполнении команды, верно? На его основе вполне можно придумать алгоритм извлечения результата выполнения команды из "общей массы". Собственно извлечённый результат и выводите на консоль. Вывод из консоли имеет формат `string`. Поэтому копайте в сторону функций по работе со строками и регулярных выражений.

Comment: спасибо!
Я лишь думал, что есть какой-либо нативный способ это сделать.
Например, в реализации на с под линукс в ответ на вызов system() от curl ... получался именно айпишник без лишней инфы.

Comment: И еще один связанный вопрос: запуск этого процесса у меня в цикле. Почему в текстбокс вносится строка уже после выполнения всех итераций цикла, а не последовательно?

Comment: @iamx4nd3r, простите, но подобные вопросы лучше задавать отдельно. На Ваш изначальный вопрос я, полагаю, ответил. Просто вопросы здесь принято задавать в топике по принципу один вопрос - один топик, а если речь идёт о помощи  с отладкой, то описывать проблему полностью (код, лог ошибок, желаемое поведение). Иначе в Вашей проблеме просто не разобраться.